# How to put a NPC on the tile grid in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, pixel

*Note: I believe I already answered my own question while writing it down (Rubberduck); however, I would like to get some validation on my approach, or maybe it is completely wrong.*

I have this 'Sign' NPC (not sure if it is called an NPC, though). If the player chooses to interact with the sign, a dialog box is shown. The way I implemented it now is a game object with a sprite renderer (rigidbody, collider, NPC controller logic etc.). For normal NPCs, this is not a problem. However, for objects that need to stick to a grid, it is.

There are a couple of issues with this approach: I need to cut out the image from the tilemap (in my case, Paint.NET) and import it into Unity as a new asset. This is double since I already have it in Unity on the tilemap.
Another issue is the location of the Sign NPC; I need to pixel-perfect it on the scene. So I put the sign on the tilemap just like the others, and then I need to drag it around for a perfect fix. One time, it's not a problem, but when you have 50 of these things, it's a bit cumbersome.

[image]

My current approach

1. I could add the NPC controller script to the tilemap renderer. This works, but then all the tiles have the same dialogue. Not very useful, but it may help.
2. I could go for a multiple of approach 1. So, Every tilemap renderer gets one (or two) sprites to handle each with its own dialogue. This approach feels overkill but might work.

Are there any performance issues when choosing approach 1? I know you shouldn't optimise performance during development. Still, I also don't want to "repost" this question a few months into the future.

Thank you in advance.